# Angular -> tslint Error, Definition of Rule jsdoc/newline-after-description

Tags: angular, tslint

if i run my tslint - i get this error. how can i fix it?

```
 1:1  error  Definition for rule 'jsdoc/newline-after-description' was not found  jsdoc/newline-after-description
```

my Version is:  "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^43.0.7",

Comment: Did you import the plugin in your eslint config ?

Comment: my run: ng lint - shows me this error message.

Comment: I mean, you need to add the plugin to your config ! `"plugins": [  "jsdoc" ]` !

Comment: i have not jsdoc in my config. I read after 42.0.0: https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/1353 but how can i fit it?

Answer (score 1):

add this rule in the .eslintrc.json file to fix it

```
"rules": {
  "jsdoc/newline-after-description": "off"
}
```

Comment: Hi @FTello31, does this solution also valid for the scenario, where I upgraded Angular app from v14 to v15, and upgraded Material(with MDC migration), ESLint too to v15? 
FYI, I too am getting same error as "Definition for rule 'jsdoc/newline-after-description' was not found jsdoc/newline-after-description" when I run ng test